# Memory / Segfault doing auto_arima

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to do a day based SARIMA modelling using the pmdarima package like so:

```
# Seasonal - fit stepwise auto-ARIMA
SARIMA_model = pm.auto_arima(
    df_demand_temperature[("TOTALDEMAND", "mean")],
    start_p=1,
    start_q=1,
    test="adf",
    max_p=3,
    max_q=3,
    m=365,  # is the frequency of the cycle
    start_P=0,
    seasonal=True,  # set to seasonal
    d=None,
    D=1,  # order of the seasonal differencing
    trace=False,
    n_jobs=10,
    error_action="ignore",
    suppress_warnings=True,
    stepwise=False,
)

SARIMA_model.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(15, 12))
plt.show()
```

I have varied the number of threads/processes with `n_jobs` between 1 - 24 and I'm running on the university computer system up to 200Gb of memory.

The error I get is:

```
error_job.get_result(self.timeout)
...
TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.
```

More stack dump on request.

The dataframe is roughly

```
DATETIME,TOTALDEMAND
..., ....
```

I would be interested in a direct solution to this or suggestions on better approaches to day based SARIMA modelling.